# Is it possible to create a stored procedure that, given an arbitrary table, returns a dummy row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I am wondering whether it's possible to create a procedure like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDummyRow 
    @table_name VARCHAR(128)
BEGIN
  -- ... 
END
```

that inserts into a table with name `@table_name` a dummy row and returns it from the procedure. Expect that `@table_name` has a primary key.

For example, if I have a table like

```
==========================================
                Persons
============================================
 id | first_name | last_name    | spouse_id 
============================================
 1  |   "John"   |  "Skeet"     |     2 
 2  |   "Jane"   |  "Skeet"     |     1
 3  |  "Bjarne"  | "Stroustrup" |    NULL
```

created with

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
   id INT AUTO_INCREMEMENT,
   first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   spouse_id INT,
   PRIMARY KEY id,
   FOREIGN KEY spouse_id REFERENCES Persons.id
)
```

and I want

```
DECLARE @t VARCHAR(128);
@t = 'Persons';
EXEC GetDummyRow(@t)
```

to return

```
4 | "ASDbaj" | "OEROANkaskoaASDOLJ" | NULL
```

or

```
4 | "okasdALAJajdlaLashdasi" | "OEROANkaskoaASDOLJadasd" | 3
```

for example.

Is there any logical reason why this would be impossible to make?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but it would be very arduous to write.   I'd seriously look for another way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah the complexities of this is going to get staggering pretty quickly. You are trying to create some sort of dynamic code that will insert random values into any table. This starts to get really difficult, if not borderline impossible, with some datatypes. You also have to consider existing foreign keys and constraints so your insert doesn't fail. It could be done but it would take an unbelievable amount of effort to make it robust enough to actually work. And given the dynamic nature it would likely be really slow too!!

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified a lot if you can use default values to specify the values for the dummy row.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
   id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Dummy',
   last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Value',
   spouse_id INT
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE GetDummyRow (@table_name NVARCHAR(128))
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
  SET @sql = N'INSERT INTO ' + @table_name + N' DEFAULT VALUES
  SELECT * FROM ' + @table_name + N' WHERE id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()'
  exec sp_executesql @sql  
END
GO

EXEC GetDummyRow 'Persons'
```

If the values need to be random, you can use NEWID() as the default:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons 
(
   id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
   last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
   spouse_id INT
)
GO
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85776/1

Comment: If you can use the same value this is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no there is no reason to think this is impossible to make.  As commented it could get complicated...

There are a few requirements that are not quite clear.  When you say dummy data you do not say random or unique but I am guessing that you would not want the same dummy data for each row.  That would require extra coding based on how many data types you want to support.

I would create a cursor based on the table schema. Then while looping through the columns build in code for the data types and constraints / indexes.  Is it a primary or foreign key, is it autonumber or is there a check constraint.  You can start small and build in exception handling for table/columns that do not fit the most anticipated types.

Depending on the architecture and complexity of your database you can take advantage of things like autonumbered primary keys.

If there is a foreign key you can either choose a key from the referenced table at random (ie. Top 1 ... From) or call the procedure recursively to insert a dummy record in that table and return the new key.  This would require putting most of the functionality in an inner procedure that returns a primary key and a wrapper that returns the result set you are looking for.

I believe these links will be a good start, looking up the topics will lead to other examples.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177862.aspx